# SFTP Ubuntu 14.04 - Patient Records Download

Tags: server, ssh, vsftpd, sftp

I need to build out a server for Insurance Companies / lawyers to download patient records.  I'm thinking that sftp is a good choice, but I would like some feedback.  I have looked at vsftpd as well, but I was told that sftp would be a better choice.  Here's a list of our requirements.

- Each user must have their own home folder (not shared) & jailed to their folder
- Records must be secure
- download only, no upload
- no ssh access
- A web interface for our Medical Records department to upload files and create user  accounts

Those downloading files will be external to our network, so keep this in mind when providing feedback & I want to follow best practices.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

### For file transport:

I'd recommend (Open)VPN for client connections with password and certificates. A secure tunnel is a must for delicate data like this.

If I where you, I'd put something like a pfsense in front of that (a GW-Application, it also contains OpenVPN). At least put an iptables Firewall on the server itself, both would be even better.

On top of that, use a secured transportation. Vsftp(d) is quite a good choice for your endeavor.

### For Storage:

I'd recommend to use normal system-Users (maybe with encryted Home-Folders better yet a luks encrypted home partition?) and a disk quota could come in handy, too.

I'd use an extra partition for /home

### For the User:

You simply could use WinSCP or Filezilla, simple to work with, easy to install, works.

### For your department:

Make sure that the admin-interface of the web-application has limited access to the staff and admin only (Deny from All, Allow from IP('s)) via webserver config.

If your company has a fixed ip use an additional IPSEC-Tunnel to the GW-Application or to the server.

### Concerns about ssh logins:

No need for that if you disable password logins and activate ssh key only login.